# iOS Keyboard extension

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8, ios8-extension

I can't select the keyboard extension I added.Namely,  I added my custom keyboard application extension target.I then build and run the target with an application and went to 
Settings > General > Keyboard > Keyboards  -> Add New Keyboard and added my new keyboard. 
I now have English, Emoji and myKeyboard under Keyboards. I then go back to the application i 
started the keyboard with and tap on a text field and the standard iOS keyboard pops up. I try to tap and hold the globe button and only English and Emjoi keyboards are available for selecting. Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing it on simulator, you will not be able to choose your custom keyboard extension from the keyboard menu in your container app. it is known issue in Xcode 6.1, hasn't fixed by apple yet .
You can try display your keyboard in the stock contacts app on the simulator, or you could just run your app on real device.